# Optimal way to get a single child element

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, linq-to-xml

We have C# code that walks various XML documents that we create. Often we need to get a known child element (it can be the only child or there could be other siblings). I have a function that given a parent and the child name will return the child element:

```
public static XmlElement GetChildElement(XmlElement parentElement, string childName) 
{
    return parentElement.GetElementsByTagName(childName).Cast<XmlElement>().FirstOrDefault();
}
```

This works fine but the other day I wondered if it could be done cleaner and easier with XPath or LINQ to XML. Most of the XPath examples I have found seem to want to know the entire structure of the document and I want a generic function that just knows about the parent and child. Linq to XML seems more promising but I haven't found an example matching what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given what you already have, you can just do this:

```
public static XmlElement GetChildElement(XmlElement parentElement, string childName) 
{
    return parentElement[childName];
}
```

This will return the first matching child element, or null if there is none.  Heck, I'm not sure there's even much sense using a convenience method for this, but the above modification will work if you already have references to this method.

One thing to note here is that the code you provided doesn't return the first matching *child* element; it returns the first matching *descendant* element. If that is in fact what you want, you can do this:

```
public static XmlElement GetChildElement(XmlElement parentElement, string childName) 
{
    return parentElement.SelectSingleNode("//" + childName) as XmlElement;
}
```

Comment: Thanks not sure how I've missed that.

Answer (score 6):

Well LINQ to XML makes this *very* easy - you just use the [`XContainer.Element`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element.aspx) method:

```
XElement child = parent.Element(elementName);
```

This will give you the first element if there are any, or null otherwise.

Comment: Currently we have XmlElements. Is there an easy to convert it to an XElement or do I have to change all of the code that is walking the documents to use XContainers?

Comment: +1 to use XElement, @BradPatton - I've posted sample for XmlElement.

Comment: @JLRishe's answer seems the most straightforward for now. Will definitely look into switching to LINQ parsing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[XmlNode.SelectSingleNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb63z0tw.aspx) is the method you looking for if you can't use XElement:

```
 var result = parentElement.SelectSingleNode(
      string.Format("*[local-name()='{0}']", nameWithoutPrefix));
```

Note that my sample cheats with namespaces (accepts any), you should understand if you need to support namespaces correctly in your case.